# How to increase the badge number

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, push-notification

I'm using firebase notification. how to increase badge number.

I'm using firebase for push notifications(APNS).

Answer (score 4):

In iOS, app displays the badge number sent from server.
So if server send a push notification with badge number 10 , then 10 will be displayed in the app badge.

To Update Badge number from inside the app, you can use UIApplication method - 

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:valueYouSet];`

However, once a new notification received, it will be updated again from payload.